# OneToMany is not loaded in second level entity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, lazy-loading

I'm using spring-data-mongodb 1.8.2 (spring-boot-starter 1.3.1) and I have a fairly easy case at hand (in which I added fetch eager in desperation):

```
@Document(collection = "class_room")
public class ClassRoom implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@NotNull
@Field("name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne**(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)**
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
private School school;
[...]
}

@Document(collection = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@NotNull
@Field("name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school"**, fetch = FetchType.EAGER**)
private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();
[...]
}
```

The repositories:
    public interface SchoolRepository extends MongoRepository {

```
}

public interface ClassRoomRepository extends MongoRepository<ClassRoom,String> {

 }
```

And the resources:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/schools",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<School> getAllSchools() {
    return schoolRepository.findAll();
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/classRooms",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<ClassRoom> getAllClassRooms() {
    return classRoomRepository.findAll();
        }
```

Now, can someone explain to me why the articles are correctly loaded when I perform the 'schoolRepository.findAll()'
but not when I perform the 'classRoomRepository.findAll()'?

And how can I make it happen?

TL;DR
A School has set of Articles
A classRoom has a School.
When I access a school directly: I see the set of Article
When access a school through a classRoom, the set of Article is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to using object associations is a bit off. In Spring Data with Mongo the concepts of defining annotations to describe how associations happen is not the standard approach.

If you see the documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html it helps to provide more clarity.

But to highlight, Mongo uses the concept of embedded objects and so ideally your data structure can be something like:

```
@Document(collection = "class_room")
public class ClassRoom implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;

private School school;
// Where School has the following fields and structure:
// private String id;
// private String name;
// private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>()
}
```

If you want school to be embedded in ClassRoom you leave it as above, else you can have School as a separate collection of its own. So:

```
@Document(collection = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

private String name;

private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();
[...]
}
```

In the above School, it is a collection of its own and is not embedded in ClassRoom.

Typically, you have to just think differently from your traditional ORM approach when dealing with Mongo, or a NoSQL/Graph database.

Comment: I understand my implementation is very much relational.
What would be the proper way to structure a model School - ClassRoom - Student then?
In one and only document 'School'?

Comment: It depends on your preferences and the context of your problem. You can structure it all in one document E.g. School or you can create multiple documents with links (E.g. ClassRoom having schoolId). 

I use both approaches on projects. If I don't see the need for an entity to stand alone then I embed it. However, if I see the need for an entity to stand on its own (E.g. the entity is shared and used by many other entities), then I make an entity for it and then link that entity to others using its Id.

Comment: I'm still not sure. in the link you provide (mapping chapter) there is an example of a 
Person being linked to an Account (DBREF).
It doesn't look like a bad practice, but then again, I'm very new at this.
I tried to follow your advice and get the school by id.
But the list of article I get is... partial. Some fields are missing.
I don't understand this logic, I considering going back to a relational DB.